# How to put 2 variables together

Tags: python

On python my current code is:

```
Import random 
Import sys
Import os
Print ("Hello! What is your name traveller?")
    name = sys.stdin.readline ()
    training = ",we are in peril! Start your training 
    now!"
first_mission = (name + training)
    Print (first_mission)
```

It then runs like this: (example name: Dave)

```
Dave  
,We are under peril! Start your training now!
```

How do I make it run like this:

```
Dave , We are under peril! Start your training now!
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason your not just using the built in input function to get a name?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to do this:

```
import random 
import sys
import os

print("Hello! What is your name traveller?")

name = input()

training = " ,we are in peril! Start your training 
now!"

first_mission = (name + training)
print(first_mission)
```

*Why?*

It'd save you quite a bit of trouble. When you call the `sys.stdin.readline()` function, the text is read and a newline (\n) is put at the end of it. This is why your text is on different lines.

Comment: You could get rid of the imports too.

Comment: @Kurt Good point. They may want it further in their program though.

Answer (score 0):

Unless theres a typo/misformat in there somewhere, just add a space after the comma?

```
training = ", we are in peril! Start your training
```

Comment: It appears to me that OP is talking about an added newline.

Comment: Yes, looks like it. at the time, wasnt formatted as is now, and only visible difference was the space

Comment: Then just trim?